# Facing an error when deploying React app to github pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, build

I'm trying to deploy my react app to github pages but facing some errors.

At first, when I tried to run `npm run deploy` in the terminal, it showed me this error:

```
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
 ^
```

And `MiniCssExtractPlugin is not a constructor`

After that, I tried: `npm i -D --save-exact mini-css-extract-plugin@2.4.5`
This solved the problem but when I ran it again (`npm run deploy`), I get this error:

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

The target environment doesn't support dynamic import() syntax so it's not possible to use 
external type 'module' within a script
```

I don't know why it doesn't work, and also didn't find anything on the internet.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you include your `import` statement for clarity? It seems like that's where the problem is.

Comment: I don't know, the terminal does not show any other thing, like a line reference from which the error is causing, other than what I already mentioned.

Comment: However, I used import in several files to import different components, are u asking for that?